# Proving that an integer, $x = q+s$ exists using the well ordering principle

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

From Serge Lang's Undergraduate Algebra

Let $x$ be a real number. Prove that there exists an integer $q$ and a real number $s$
which is greater than or equal to zero and strictly less than $1$, such that $x = q+s,$ and that $q$ and $s$ are uniquely determined.

I understand that the basic implication of the well-ordering principle is that if you can prove there is a least element in a set, then the set is nonempty. However, in this scenario
I'm struggling to see how it could be applied. Only $s$ is bounded, whereas $q$ could be anything. Should I even be using the well ordering principle?

Comment: "if you can prove there is a least element in a set, then the set is nonempty." That's true, but silly. If there is an element in a set, then the set is non-empty. So I think you have miss-typed whatever you meant to type there, or you're just confused? Anyway, From wikipedia, "the well-ordering principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element".

Answer (score 2):

1. Prove there exists an integer less than or equal to $x,$ maybe using the Archimedean property of $R$.
2. Prove there is a greatest integer less than or equal to $x,$ maybe with proof by contradiction.
3. Show that $x+1$ is the least integer greater than $x.$
4. Show uniqueness of $s$ and $q$ by assuming that $s'$ and $q'$ also exist and then arrive at a contradiction.

Or something like that.

I'm not sure you need $3.$ But those some ideas. I don't have your book, so the exact way you answer your questions depends on the details in your book up until this question...

Comment: Maybe this is not what the question-asker wants though, because I'm probably avoiding the well-ordering principle. Hmm...

Comment: I watched Serge Lang's book about this exercise. It's on page 5 after introducing the terminology of sets, well-ordering of integers, and induction, without any words about the construction of the real numbers. I don't know if I did it right or not.

Comment: Your step 2 is equivalent to the well-ordering principle, so you are not avoiding it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstood the author's words in the well-ordering of natural numbers. What the author says is that (in page 2):

> *Every non-empty set of integers $\geq$ 0 has a least element.*
>
> (This means: If $S$ is a non-empty set of integers $\geq$ 0, then there exists an integer $n \in S$ such that $n \leq x$ for all $x \in S$.)

Your words seems taking it in the wrong direction:

> if you can prove there is a least element in a set, then the set is nonempty.

It should be "if the set is nonempty,  there is a least element in it".

Then for this exercise, I have to use a fact(I don't know if the author relies on it or not):

> (i) For any real number there is some interger $\geq 0$ greater than this real number.
>
> (ii) Especially, there is some integer $N \geq 0$ such that $N > x$

just take the set to be:

$$
S = \{m \in \Bbb{Z} |  m \geq N - x \}
$$

. From (i) $S$ is nonempty, then apply the well-ordering of natural numbers to conclude that $S$ has a least element $n$. And then take $q = N -n$ and $s = x - q$

Comment: The fact you reference is called the Archimedean principle, as Adam Rubinson mentions. Given that, your proof works. To prove the Archimedean principle, by the supremum property (a defining property of the Real numbers) the natural numbers, if they are bounded above by some real number $x$, has a supremum $s$. But then $s-1$ must be less than some natural number $N$, which means $s < N+1$, a contradiction.